# Template is missing when using redirect_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 3 app, I have a Results controller. When im on the show.html.erb page using the show action in the controller, I have a link to a filter action. When the filter action is done, i want it to redirect back to the show.html.erb, but for some reason it keeps saying `Template is missing Missing template results/filter` . Im using ajax, so there is a fitler.js.rjs file, but i cant figure this out. If i remove the filter.js.rjs file, it gives me `Unknown action The action 'filter' could not be found for ResultsController`

Heres my code for the results action. Any help is appreciated.

```
def filter
            @dispatches = Dispatch.find_by_message_ids(params[:message_ids]) unless params[:message_ids].blank?

            unless @dispatches.blank? || @input_messages.blank?
            @output_messages = OutputMessage.find_by_dispatch_ids(
                                              @dispatches.collect{|d| d.id }.uniq
                                              )
            end

            respond_to do |format|
                  format.html { redirect_to show_path }
                  format.js
            end
    end
```

**UPDATE**

Here's the code on show.html.erb that calls the filter action

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "results", :action => "filter", :remote => true) do %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work. The problem was my form tag. It was outputting `action="/results/filter/?remote=true"` so i changed my form_tag to :

```
 <%= form_tag url_for(:controller => "results", :action => "filter"), :remote => true do %>
```

And it worked! But that uses HTML5, now im going to find a workaround for non-HTML5

Answer (score 1):

redirect_to show_path won't work; the "show" action expects an id or an object instance. In Rails 3 you can redirect directly to an object, e.g. redirect_to @user which will default to the show method on that object. You can also redirect to the action with redirect_to(:action => "show", :id => NN) where you supply the id manually and optionally specify the controller. Or in the old-fashioned way redirect_to show_user_path(@user).

Comment: Yeah so i switched the `show_path` to `:action => "show"` and still didnt work so I moved the entire filter block to above the show block and now it works. Very strange. But now theres another error.. `Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note...` Because the show uses a redirect on error.. is there away to tell rails to bypass any redirects after the redirect?

Comment: Can you update your example above with the new code or give us a gist?

Comment: Im running into a bunch of problems. Im going to try and sort things out and then maybe open a new question.. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your form has `:remote => true` and this prompts the rails that the incoming request is an ajax call and hence rails would look for filter.js.rjs file and it would never look for the html file. hence u get the error when u remove the rjs file.

Comment: Yeah but there is a filter.js.rjs and its still giving me template not found.

Comment: is there a call to a partial anywhere?

Comment: Yes. The contents of the filter.js.rjs are as follows: `page.insert_html :top, :fitler, :partial => "fiter"`

Comment: Also, I moved the filter action block to above the show action and i am getting the error `Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please ....`

Comment: try giving elaborate path for ur partial.

Comment: Im pretty sure it finds the partial because by default when show.html.erb loads, it successfully loads the partial.